# AssertionError: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, while spiltting the data into test and train

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I am following this tutorial [Time Series Modeling using Scikit, Pandas, and Numpy](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-modeling-using-scikit-pandas-and-numpy-682e3b8db8d1), i have this data in my  dataframe (data_consumption)

[image]

but when i am trying to split it into train and test using this code

```
X_train = data_consumption[:'2019'].drop(['DAILY_AQI_VALUE'], axis = 1)
y_train = data_consumption.loc[:'2019', 'DAILY_AQI_VALUE']
```

it is giving me this error:

```
AssertionError     Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-64-b7ef74aa038e> in <module>
----> 1 X_train = data_consumption[:'2019-01'].drop(['DAILY_AQI_VALUE'], axis = 1)
      2 y_train = data_consumption.loc[:'2016', 'DAILY_AQI_VALUE']

~\.conda\envs\UU_Smog\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
__getitem__(self, key)    2883             # either we have a slice or we have a string that can be converted    2884             #  to a slice for partial-string date indexing
-> 2885             return self._slice(indexer, axis=0)    2886     2887         # Do we have a (boolean) DataFrame?

~\.conda\envs\UU_Smog\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
_slice(self, slobj, axis)    3555         Slicing with this method is *always* positional.    3556         """
-> 3557         assert isinstance(slobj, slice), type(slobj)    3558         axis = self._get_block_manager_axis(axis)    3559         result = self._constructor(self._mgr.get_slice(slobj, axis=axis))

AssertionError: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not working tutorial code you can try upgrade pandas or use this alternative solution with filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = data_consumption[data_consumption.index.year < 2019]
X_train = df1.drop(['DAILY_AQI_VALUE'], axis = 1)
y_train = df1['DAILY_AQI_VALUE']
```

Comment: Thanks it worked , do i have to write the same code with test but flipping the sign of < to > 2019 like this  df2 = data_consumption[data_consumption.index.year > 2019]
X_test = df1.drop(['DAILY_AQI_VALUE'], axis = 1)
y_test = df1['DAILY_AQI_VALUE']

Comment: Thank you @jezrael it worked perfectly. Thank you , You are pro :)